# Find record by one of the composite primary keys

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have composite primary key in one of my tables in Java web app using Hibernate framework:

For example:

```
@Embeddable
public class Student implements Serializable {    
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private String studentId;

    @Column(name = "course_code")
    private String courseCode;
}
```

I can filter records by both fields. However, I want to search for a record with `studentId` only. How would it be possible in Hibernate?

Comment: Do you want get `Student` with `studentId`?

Comment: Yes, regardless of `courseCode`.

Comment: Use a query. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql

Comment: Nevermind, I got it! I used `Student.studentId` on my HQL.

Comment: You make do this by `Hibernate Criteria` with following my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("student_id", student_id));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("course_code", course_code));
List list = criteria.list();
```